# How to properly check for keywords with MYSQL "LIKE"

Tags: php, mysql

I am wondering how I can properly check keywords with SQL "LIKE";

I have a script which looks like that:

```
$search_keywords = $_POST['search-keywords'];
$search_keywords = str_replace(" ","%", $search_keywords);
$search_keywords = '%' . $search_keywords . '%';
$search = $odb -> query("SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE `keywords` LIKE '".$search_keywords."' ORDER BY `id` ASC");
$rows = $search->rowCount();
if ($rows > 0) {//Loop}
```

In fact, it's working but only when keywords in the database look like that:

`audi, a3, silver` and I search for `audi a3`

If i am trying to search like that: `a3 audi` it's not working

Any hints?

Comment: You need to LIKE the keywords separately.

Comment: You shouldn't use comma-separated lists. Create a new table with one row for each keyword, then you don't need `LIKE`.

Comment: you should really reactor the db, as Barmer says above: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: @tadman FTS is overkill for searching keyword lists.

Comment: @Barmar For keyword data, sure, but in a more general sense it may avoid the need for old-school tags altogether. This does need proper normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split `$search_keywords` into separate words, and search for each of them.

To search for an item in a comma-separated list, use `FIND_IN_SET()` rather than `LIKE`. `LIKE '%audi%'` will also match audi-quatro.

```
$keyword_array = explode(" ", $_POST['search_keywords']);
foreach ($keyword_array as &$keyword) {
    $keyword = "FIND_IN_SET('$keyword', keywords)";
}
$tests = implode(' AND ', $keyword_array);
// $tests contains something like: FIND_IN_SET('a3', keywords) AND FIND_IN_SET('audi', keywords)
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE $tests ORDER BY `id` ASC";
$search = $odb->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a best practice to use `PDO::prepare` when you are passing user data in your request, to evoid `SQL Injection`

```
$search = $odb->prepare("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE keywords 
    LIKE CONCAT('%',:keyword,'%') 
    ORDER BY id ASC");
$results = $search->execute([":keywork" => $search_keywords]);
```

Comment: You can also concat the `%` part in the `execute` call, which cleans up the query considerably.

Comment: His problem is searching for multiple keywords in any order. How does this solve it?